# Opencart Query new db table

Tags: php, opencart

i'm struggling to cross-reference a new db table in an Opencart installation. I've tried a few version, but this is my closest. Still breaks the site though.

If i call this at the bottom of a product.tpl file - why will it not work?

```
    <?php 
    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `oc_product_newtabcontent` WHERE `product_id` = '1956'");
    if($result){
    echo 'Successfully retrieved ' . $result;
    } else {
    echo 'There was a problem';
    }; ?>
```

Comment: You have a pretty obvious syntax error

Comment: Sorry - fixed that. Still no results.

Comment: What exactly does "Still breaks the site" mean?  Is this your exact code, copy/pasted from your editor?  Do you actually have single-quotes around your table name instead of the correct backticks?

Comment: I have fixed the Syntax again - sorry. It doesn't break the site anymore. But nothing is echoed out even though i know there are results in the table for those details.

Comment: "nothing is echoed out"  _Nothing_?  Not even 'There was a problem'?  Please remember that you need to be detailed in your description of what's going on.  You also need to take some time and do some basic debugging.  If this code truly does create _no output at all_, then you need to add some debugging statements further back in your code to track down when the last spot is that it does what you expect.

Comment: In OC all query's should be placed in the corresponding model files. Than you retrieve that data in controller file and pass to the template file.